# In my Cordova Android app i am unable to embed an ip address or URL in an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

No Iframe will not load in this page except fro the youtube video url. 
I get the following error code when I use any other iframe url.
Error : net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

In the blow example, any URL or ip address fails to load with the same error.

But the embedded youtube video loads and works perfectly.

This is my Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 'self' http: style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'https://www.google.com/' ">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <iframe width="360" height="715" src="https://google.com/" target="_parent"/></iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
<access origin="http://192.168.0.106/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.106/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://192.168.0.106/*" />  
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://192.168.0.106/" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://192.168.0.106/*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the request to `http://google.com` you can see that it returns a

```
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

header. This instructs the browser to not load the page if the parent is not on the same domain. YouTube doesn't have it probably because it wants you to be able to embed it's videos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: My understanding is that adding <access origin="*"/> to my config.xml is supposed to fix that?

Comment: Unless you work for Google, no. What `google.com` is saying is that it explicitly doesn't want to be used in the way that you intend. You can however load any domain you control because you can set the security policy.